# What are my options for getting from Barranquilla (Colombia) airport into town?

Tags: public-transport, colombia, barranquilla

Well, the title is pretty self explanatory.

It seems I can expect a taxi to cost about 10 USD (or the equivalent). Can anyone confirm?

Is there a shuttle bus? Or perhaps a simple scheduled bus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikitravel has a get in section from the airport](http://wikitravel.org/en/Barranquilla).

Evidently they believe the taxis to be $8-$12, so maybe you can negotiate towards the lower end.

There's the public buses, not comfortable, but $0.55 or less - so hey, bargain.  They do go on to say that it's not that ideally situated to the city center, but perhaps you could bus in, and then take a taxi to wherever you're going.

I searched a bit longer, and checked with my ex-flatmate who is from Colombia, but there doesn't appear to be a shuttle service.

Comment: I had seen the Barranquilla entry on wikitravel, but overlooked the airport reference under the bus section. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general, taxis in Colombia are negotiated prices. There is a stand in BAQ which sets fares, and will sell you a "ticket" which you then give to a taxi driver, who will take you to your destination and get reimbursed from the "ticket". (But tip the driver - that's not included.) Traveling with my family, we flew BOG to BAQ then took a taxi to Cartagena (2½ hours) using the taxi stand at BAQ.